# How to change color font depending status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change dynamically color font depending status in a table:
Approved - green
Pending - yellow
Rejected - red

how can achieve it?

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="table" id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Application</th>
            <th>Tier1</th>
            <th>Manager</th>
            <th>Director<br>
            <th>VP</th>
            <th>Overall</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>OMS</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Approved</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
            <td>Rejected</td>
            <td>Pending</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: how is your table currently being created (if you create it can you add a class to the `td`)? do you use jquery?

Comment: i was trying with this code:
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Approved";
    if (str==""){
    var result = str.fontcolor("green");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
</script>

Comment: @edwinbossman you should add that code to your question and explain what the error was/why you think it wasn't working.

Comment: i've tried but it was not properly formatting

Comment: @EdwinBossman According to MDN, the `fontcolor` method has been deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor

Comment: @EdwinBossman format it with newline before code block and four spaces at the beginning of every line! See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var getColor = function(text) {
  if (text === "Approved") return 'green';
  if (text === "Pending") return 'yellow';
  if (text === "Rejected") return 'red';
  return "";
};

$('td').each(function(i, td) {
  var color = getColor($(td).html());
  $(td).css({
    "color": color
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <table class="table" id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Application</th>
      <th>Tier1</th>
      <th>Manager</th>
      <th>Director<br>
        <th>VP</th>
        <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>OMS</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 4):

you can use jquery to add the relevant class:

```
$( "td" ).addClass( "approved" );
$( "td" ).addClass( "pending" );
```

or you can use vanilla js:

```
  var element = document.getElementById("tdId");
    element.classList.add("approved");
```

the css of these classes is like:

```
.approve {
color: green;
}

.pending{
color: yellow;
}

.rejected{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: not working properly, i got answer in below answer, thanks a lot